# Converting User Input Data?

Tags: php, forms, input, iso-8859-1

My form has issues with latin characters (portuguese). If the user submitted his info with special characters, I get the info on my email with messed up characters. The rest is fine (the form page presents special characters ok, it's only the emails I receive that have messed up characters with the user's info).

Long story short, I may have found where to fix it. The Where, but not the How.

Here is the bit where I think it can be fixed:

```
    $content = $fields['name'] . " has sent you a message through the your Form:\r\n\n";
    $content .= "-------\n" . $fields['message'] . "\r\n\n";
    $content .= "Contact reason: " . $fields['contact_reason']
            . " \n\nEmail: " . $fields['email']
            . " \n\nPhone: " . $fields['phone'] . " \n\n";
```

How to add some code to it so that i can convert the user input data to ISO-8859-1? Or is this not the right place to do it?

P.S.: This is a script I purchased. The owner did not reply back and does not offer support.

Comment: If the developer does not give any support put his name somewhere on the internet for other people to stop buying his code. Every developer selling his code should give at least minimum support to his clients. If he is not, don't buy his work...

Comment: Completely agree.  I can post here if you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you must know whether the Portuguese characters can be fully converted to ISO-8859-1 (check this, not even all European languages can be converted, e. g. Hungarian ő and ű can't be converted to ISO-8859-1). If not, you'll have to change settings of your email. If yes, you might want to use [utf8_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php), [mbstring](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) or [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

Comment: Yes, ISO-8859-1 is the only way portuguese characters show up on my form.php page. 
<br/>
But the sending.php page is the one that must have the problem. And that is where I'm trying to add or somehow convert user input data.

I have tried a lot of things:



I have tried:

iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
and
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
and
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
and
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
and
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
      <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed.

The solution was adding MIME to the specific field in the first post.